# Apply shopping cart rule on original price & not with Special Price

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to make a  shopping cart rule that applies to the original prices of each product not over special prices.

I was thinking to override `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule` model.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well for the record i have done this:

i overrode cart controller (Mage_Checkout_CartController) the methods:
addaction, deleteAction ,updateItemOptionsAction

so i check for applied rules with:

```
 $appliedRuleIds = $this->_getSession()->getQuote()
            ->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

and then if it is my rule id,

i do this:

```
   foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $quote) {
                    //get original price not special
                    $productPrice = $quote->getProduct()->getPrice();
                    $quote->setOriginalCustomPrice($productPrice);
                    // setCustomPrice
                    $quote->save();
                }
```

so the cart now has the original prices of the products